# Output file with three words on each line - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, newline

I have a file which has a list of words all on different lines for example:

```
cat
dog
horse
pig
sheep
mouse
```

I would like to write something in python that joins 3 words together in one line seperated by spaces and continues through the file with the sample output being something like this:

```
cat dog horse
pig sheep mouse
```

Is this possible? I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Yes it's possible.  People generally won't be inclined to help you if you haven't started it yourself and attempted to do it though.

Comment: your file contains multiple of 3, if like you have 11 lines then?? i.e not multipe of 3??

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy! [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

content = open("/tmp/words").read()
step   = 3
# get line content and skip blank lines
words  = [line for line in content.split("\n") if line ]

for group in izip_longest(*[iter(words)] * step, fillvalue=""): 
    print " ".join(group) # join by spaces
```

Comment: might be worth adding a link to the itertools docs as this is the grouper function, you should also use with to open files or at least close them after

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham! I had added a link to doc. Regarding  "with" keyword I think it is out of scope here.

Comment: why do you think the using a context manager is out of scope?

Answer (score 0):

first you open the file and read it in

```
 file_contents = open("some_file.txt").read().split()
```

then you open a file to write to

```
 with open("file_out.txt","w") as f:
```

then you do magic

```
     f.write("\n".join(" ".join(row) for row in zip(*[iter(file_contents)]*3)))
```

Comment: I always Love your code but he is newbiee, not helpful him

Answer (score -2):

```
f=open('your_file','r')
f=f.readlines()
for x in [ " ".join(b[x-3:x]).replace('\n','') for x in range(1,len(b)) if x%3==0 ]
    print x
if len(f)%3 > 0:
   print " ".join(b[-(len(b)%3):]).replace('\n','')
```

example:

```
a=['cat','dog','bat','hello','baby','stack','overflow','python','code','search','string']
output will be:
'cat dog bat'
'hello baby stack'
'overflow python code'
'search string'
```

, 
open file, read file using `readlines()` then check for multiple of three, and at last check for mod for, last element when its not multiple of three